# How to find the location of a audio file that's played on a button click to grab it with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

When I click a button audio plays, I'm not extremely familiar with javascript, this is the HTML code of the button:

```
<div class="voice-speaker bg-audio-speaker-on" ng-click="self.onRefreshClick()" ng-class="{ playing: self.isSoundPlaying }" style="background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170); height: 200px; width: 200px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"> <div ng-show="self.soundFileQueue.isElectronicVoicePlaying" class="electronic ng-hide">Electronic</div> </div>
```

Im assuming it's calling self.onRefreshClick(), but where would I find the code onRefreshClick runs?

Comment: add website and code you've done so far !!

Comment: you need an account but it's https://www.educationperfect.com/ and any activity with spoken to text. Cant add code but I'm using basic bs4

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of hard to answer without seeing the HTML file itself. Generally speaking there should be some type of script section to that HTML file where that should be defined. I'm not entirely sure what convention is, but I generally put all my javascript at the bottom of the HTML file, so you might start there. It should look something like this:

```
<script>
some javascript for onRefreshClick here
</script>
```

If that doesn't work, then I would suggest just using `Ctrl + f` and searching it that way, which will will probably be the quickest. If you are using your browser's inspect functionality, then there should be a search option at the top somewhere too.

Comment: I found a few script tags, but no onRefreshClick here's a bit of the code at the bottom: https://0bin.net/paste/uOLs64MD#32ODlQca6lxXSeWmIHJghTPlUDyfMrTPpPATPNwULqY